# Split ArrayList based on word

Tags: java, arraylist

Attempting (and failing) to split an ArrayList based on a 'start word'.

The ArrayList is a collection of sockets, originally a HashSet -

```
[[Socket[addr=/192.168.150.210,port=2001,localport=49671], Socket[addr=/192.168.150.211,port=2001,localport=49670], Socket[addr=/192.168.150.215,port=2001,localport=49672], Socket[addr=/192.168.150.213,port=10001,localport=49669]]]
```

In need to somehow split that array so I end up with a new ArrayList that then contains distinct elements (each beginning Socket[ etc so I can then iterate through (based on size) looking for a matching IP address.

i.e (as 4 'records')

```
Socket[addr=/192.168.150.210,port=2001,localport=49671]
Socket[addr=/192.168.150.211,port=2001,localport=49670]
Socket[addr=/192.168.150.215,port=2001,localport=49672]
Socket[addr=/192.168.150.213,port=10001,localport=49669]
```

I cant use for i = on the original ArrayList because its size is 1 record ( need 4 records)

i.e.

```
Object currentSock = null; 

for (int i =0; i<  theseSocks.size(); i++)
{
currentSock = theseSocks.get(i);
if (currentSock.toString().contains(ipAddress))
{
System.out.println(" the ArrayList element is " +currentSock);
break;
}
}
```

Thoughts appreciated (I am a newbie).
Regards
Ralph

Comment: Could you give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: use a for loop on `OriginalArrayList.get(0)`?

Comment: I have amended the original post to show the required output. Please elaborate on how get(0) will work (based on finding the socket with a matching IP address) as there is only 1 record

Comment: What is the type of elements in the Array?

Comment: Sockets populated from a HashSet originally. Cant convert to string or any other type because I need to 'reuse' the actual socket.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to convert it to a string if you're looking for an IP address of a given socket.

Comment: All the 'solutions' I have read about so far require converting to string in order to split, something I do not want,

Comment: *...converting to string in order to split, something I do not want* Why?

Comment: @tima is right. Use for loop, with "theseSocks.get(0).get(i)"

Comment: @forpas Because it's pointless; you can compare the internet address you're looking for with the socket IP address, and skip strings, string compares, splits, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's better practice not to filter or find by generating a string representing the entire object.  Match based on the property of interest instead, which in your case is the IP address.

In Java 8 and beyond, there is a feature called streams that makes this very quick.

In this case, I'm still using the inetAddress toString to string match the IP, but not calling toString on the whole object.

The line of interest looks like this:

```
Optional< Socket > matchingSocket = sockets.stream().findAny().filter( socket -> socket.getInetAddress().toString().equals( "/192.168.0.1" ) );
```

A runnable example follows.  You need the targets to actually connect, or you will get dropped into the exception handling.  So you need to find computers willing to accept connections on a port and change the add lines accordingly, or use your live HashSet.

```
try
{
    List< Socket > sockets = Lists.newArrayList( );
    sockets.add( new Socket( "192.168.0.1", 7777 ) );
    sockets.add( new Socket( "192.168.0.2", 7777 ) );

    Optional< Socket > matchingSocket = sockets.stream().findAny().filter( socket -> socket.getInetAddress().toString().equals( "/192.168.0.1" ) );

}
catch( Exception e )
{
    //handle this
}
```

Here is an example using a for loop instead of streams:

```
try
{
    List< Socket > sockets = Lists.newArrayList( );
    sockets.add( new Socket( "192.168.0.1", 7777 ) );
    sockets.add( new Socket( "192.168.0.2", 7777 ) );

    for( Socket socket : sockets)
    {
        if( socket.getInetAddress().toString().equals( "/192.168.0.1" ) )
            System.out.println( "Found socket " + socket.toString() );
    }

}
catch( Exception e )
{
    //handle this
}
```

Also worth noting this exact same for loop works with your HashSet.  I'm wondering if your ArrayList somehow contains a single entry of the HashSet instead of individual sockets.  You could just iterate the HashSet instead.

Replace my arraylist lines with the following to test:

```
Set< Socket > sockets = Sets.newHashSet( );
sockets.add( new Socket( "192.168.0.1", 7777 ) );
sockets.add( new Socket( "192.168.0.2", 7777 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Evan, much appreciated though I should have mentioned I am using an early java version (something sadly which cant be changed). As an aside the sockets are already connected and stored in a HashSet and then in the ArrayList but I cant see how to split that ArrayList (even if it was 4 separate arrays that would be ok).

Comment: @Ralph I don't understand the issue. It's not relevant that they're in a hash; you can still look at each entry and compare IP addresses. You're either not describing the problem well, or you're not listening to what people are saying.

Comment: The '4' sockets are in an ArrayList which thinks it has a size of 1 (and not 4), therefore I cannot use my for loop to look for a matching IP address and return the matching entire socket. There's probably a simple solution but I cant see it.

Comment: It appears that theseSocks thinks it is an object and not an array of sockets, hence the for( Socket loop will not work.

Comment: What if you iterate on the HashSet as I suggest in my edit?

Comment: Sadly I have to pass the HashSet through MySQL (don't laugh) because I have to reuse that HashSet in a frontend web application (completely seperate from the backend java process which created the initial HashSet. Reusing the HashSet and iterating through it works fine in the backend.